# How to get history of mapping for following table data

Tags: mysql

I have a history mapping table for UserId changes, where every time when UserId changes, a row for new UserId with old UserId inserted in the history table.
Below is the sample table and data:

```
UserIdNew | UserIdOld
---------------------
    5     |     1    
    10    |     5    
    15    |     10
```

The above data explains that UserId 1 has gone with following transition from UserId 1 -> 5-> 10 -> 15.

I want to query all the Old Ids for a give `UserIdNew`, how can I do it in a single query?

For this case if `UserIdNew = 15`, then it should return `1,5,10`

Comment: If Your MySQL version is 8.0, You may build recursive CTE (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive), obtaining data You need. If not, stored procedure seems to be the only solution.

Comment: You mean that you want a single row with all the members of the same "family" on that row starting with the oldest ancestor?

Comment: @Vérace Yes, fine even if in separate rows.

Answer (score 1):

[System Version Tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/system-versioned-tables/) in MariaDB-10.3 offers a range of features associated with versioning. This provides easy history viewing however its hard to trace changes.

Any table structure that preserves a unique unmodified key as the starting ID will make all required queries easier rather than resorting to CTE, procedures or other required recursive implementations.